# How to download a dataset from amazon using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, amazon-s3, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

As a personal project; I want to train a model to get distance from RGB images.

I try to download a dataset from this link 'http://diode-dataset.s3.amazonaws.com/train.tar.gz' using tensorflow like this

```py
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

tensorflow.download.DownloadManager('http://diode-dataset.s3.amazonaws.com/train.tar.gz')
```

but I get this error 
"download_and_extract() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url_or_urls'"

So I tried

```py
tensorflow.download.DownloadManager(url_or_urls='http://diode-dataset.s3.amazonaws.com/train.tar.gz')
```

but I get this error

"download_and_extract() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' "

any suggestions?

Comment: Please correct your code above, including a complete example with imports. The code you posted is not even valid Python syntax (identifiers can't have `-` in their name).

Answer (score 3):

The `tensorflow_datasets` download manager is a class, so you have to instantiate it before using it. This works for me:

```py
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

# create an instance of `DownloadManager` first
dm = tfds.download.DownloadManager(download_dir='/tmp')

# use it to download datasets
dm.download('http://diode-dataset.s3.amazonaws.com/train.tar.gz')
```